# Using Timespan as key in dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

i have this following code. It is not adding new key values to the dictionary....whats wrong??

```
while(true)
{
TimeSpan t = // some timespan which is updating every second
int value =  // some value associated with timespan

Dictionary<TimeSpan,int> _dict = new Dictionary<TimeSpan,int>();
_dict.Add(t,value);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Duplicated keys? Infinite loop (`while(true)`)?

Comment: the loop is not the problem... the keys are getting overwritten everytime i add some data.

Comment: Perhaps give us some examples which doesn't work

Comment: i am not able to add any new TimeSpan to the dictionary as key.. i can use TimeSpan as key right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are instantiating a brand new dictionary each time the loop executes

Try this:

```
Dictionary<TimeSpan,int> _dict = new Dictionary<TimeSpan,int>();
while(true)
{
       TimeSpan t = // some timespan which is updating every second
       int value =  // some value associated with timespan
       _dict.Add(t,value);
}
```

As a side note, it might make more sense to just use the total elapsed ticks or milliseconds as the key instead of a time-span object

Comment: thanks a lot @pickles ......so stupid of me... what will happen if i add duplicate keys??

Comment: If you use Add you will get an exception. If you use _dict[t] = value it will replace the existing key/value pair